# Keep focus after click

Tags: jquery, methods

I can't find the jQuery method that allows me to apply a focus on an element and keep it until another element is clicked.
A bit like toggle without the toggle effect.
I tried toggleClass(); focusin(); focus();.
The only one that worked was toggle but its behavior is not what I was looking for.
A click on an element keeps the focus and remains active as long as there is no click on another element.

Any ideas?

Sorry, but I wasn't clear enough in my explanations. I want to keep the hover behavior on click and make it disappear when I click on another element.
It is this method that I can't find.

Comment: can you please post code sample?

Comment: Both jquery `.focus()` and vanilla `.focus()` will move the browser focus to the relevant element.  If your element is not *keeping* focus, then there's something else that's taking it away - such as another .focus() call or the user tab-ing to another element.

Comment: The way you mention "keep hover behaviour" and "a focus" (rather than just "focus") makes it sound like you're trying to have an *effect* rather than specifically *focus*.   If you could describe the "effect" you're after it would help.  Likely you just want to add a css class `$(this).addClass("yourclass")` and corresponding remove from other elements.

Answer (score 0):

To apply a focus on an element you have to use the [`.focus()`](https://api.jquery.com/focus/) function without argument.

```js
$('#my_element').focus();
```

It's a shortcut to

```js
$('#my_element').trigger('focus');
```

Comment: I've tested trigger(); but it doesn't work.

Comment: @marcus, You should update your question by adding a piece of code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.focus()` method to keep focus on your input control.

```
 $("input:text").focus();
```

Comment: It doesn't work